# Why should I build my own error/exception handling into a Webflux application?

Tags: exception, spring-webflux

When there is some internal exception in a Webflux application, why do I want/need to write code to handle these exceptions? I understand handling issues and returning appropriate *ServerResponse* bodies when the service client incorrectly invokes a service, or when a non-error-condition (i.e., query returns empty cursor, etc.) occurs.

But, other than generating debug information into a logfile, is there anything to be gained by rolling-your-own exception handling components? This approach makes "more sense" to me in a monolithic application, where one is trying to avoid a scenario where the app "just dies".

But, for a service implementation, especially if there's some incentive not to expose too much about the internal implementation to a client, why wouldn't Spring's default error/exception handling (and "500 Internal Server Error" response/message) be sufficient.

Comment: one example could be that, when running the server in a test environment you want the error messages that are returned to the client to be more verbose then in production. 

So you write a custom exceptionhandler t that will give more verbose information to the client during testing. I usually also add a parameter called "debugMessage" that is returned to the client if the service is started using the "test" profile. This debugMessage anyone can pass when throwing an exception, and here you can pass detailed information about the request. Things you dont want to expose to the client in prod

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking along those lines (i.e., hiding implementation from clients in production, adding info/warning/error info to logs, etc.). There's also the "if nothing else, at least we're not using someone else's implementation" argument (not so good for bottom-line concerns, but "more better" when security considerations come into play).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some time and thought (and little, but still helpful-and-appreciated feedback), I guess it boils down to:

(a) - It provides a localized context to "do things", like logging information about the exception/error condition, or categorizing the severity of the exception within-the-context of a server-client interaction.

(b) - It provides a localized context to hide/expose information from a client, based on the nature of the exception/error condition and whether the server is deployed in a production or test environment.

(c) - Being localized, it makes maintenance/modification a bit easier, as the handling of exceptions/errors is not scattered throughout the code.

(a) and (c) are enough to make me believe it's worth the effort.